# Deal With Two Layer For Next Loop

Tags: for-loop, vbscript

I have a two layer `For Next` Loop as shown below:

```
For i = 1 To 100

    For j = 1 To 12

       Do Something

    Next

Next
```

My question is that in the inner `For Next` loop, how could I stop looping when it hits the condition and continue with `Next i`. For example, `j = 1,2,3` meet the requirement and executed; but when `j = 4` and it hits the condition, the rest of `j` `(5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)` won't be processed but start a `Next i`; and during the new loop, it is `j = 8` when it hits the condition and terminates the loop so `j = 9,10,11,12` won't be evaluated to save time. It's not always `j = 4` then exit the inner loop (if so, why don't just write `j = 1 To 4`?)

Comment: if j=4, then the inner loop never execute again, is it??

Answer (score 1):

I agree with previous answer, but it's written in Java :)

here is how you could write it in Vbscript

```
For i = 1 To 100
    For j = 1 To 12
        If j = 4 Then Exit For
        'Else do something
    Next
Next
```

unfortunately, Vbscript don't always behave like you intend, and I wouldn't be sure which for it would exit. In this case it's pretty easy, but with more nested loop, i would be afraid it behaves differently, for example depending on OS (I have this kind of issues all the time in my work!), and exit the other loop.  to avoid this, use a sub function:

```
Sub test()
    For i = 1 To 100
        F_second_Loop
    Next
End Sub
Function F_second_Loop()
    For j = 1 To 12
        If j = 4 Then Exit For
        'Else do something
    Next
End Function
```

And, yes, that happened to me that `Exit For` exit the wrong loop. took me months to find the problem!

Comment: For your first method, according to `Ekkehard Horner`, it seems like the `Exit For` would work as we expected; but thanks for the second method offered! Great inspiration! I will do some test and pick the final answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

`break` is `Exit [For|Do|Sub|Function|Property]` in VBscript (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t234253x%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)). E.g:

```
Option Explicit

Dim i, j

For i = 1 To 5
    WScript.StdOut.Write "i: " & i & " =>"
    For j = 5 To 1 Step -1
        WScript.StdOut.Write " " & j
        If i = 3 And j = 3 Then Exit For
    Next
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 28988507.vbs
i: 1 => 5 4 3 2 1
i: 2 => 5 4 3 2 1
i: 3 => 5 4 3
i: 4 => 5 4 3 2 1
i: 5 => 5 4 3 2 1
```

As you can see from the fake

```
If i = 3 And j = 3 Then Exit For
```

a better answer to your question needs more details about how to determine the limits of the `For j` loop given the current i.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you have to evaluate `j` reversely?

Answer (score 0):

The `break` statement allows you to 'break out' of a loop (as implemented by most languages):

```
for i = 1 to 100
  for j = 1 to 12
    if j == 4 break
    // do something
  next 
next
```

Comment: The inner loop always start from 1, so if you use break, then it is same as the loop, for j=1 to 4..

Comment: Indeed, but I'm assuming OP has a more complex condition and simplified for the sake of the question.

Comment: yes, the loop never reach  j>=4, then whats the need for break. @lovechillcool you have to clarify..

Comment: In that case why not write `for j to end` where `end` is the final number in a variable? Presumably this would be set in the outer for loop.

Comment: @TomWalters I don't believe VBScript has the `break` statement.

Comment: If you're using VBScript I'd suggest editing the question and adding it as a tag so as to get exposure to more people who can help. But the solution of using `for j to end` should be applicable here either way.

Comment: @TomWalters it is hard to find the end without going through each `j` from 1 to 12. Maybe I should use `Do Loop While`? But somehow my `Do Loop While` still evaluated all `1~12`...